# Unable to access localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I've installed a LAMP stack, MySQL-server, apahe2, PHPMyAdmin, but unable to access is using localhost/PHPMyAdmin. I can access MySQL using the terminal. But not through PHPMyAdmin.

I also checked `/var/www/html`, no PHPMyAdmin folder is present.
I once deleted it by mistake, I think the issue is from there.

This is the output :

[image: image 1]

Comment: refer this [ https://askubuntu.com/questions/168191/where-is-my-phpmyadmin-installation ]

Comment: again same output.

Comment: better reinstall

Comment: Started this,  hope the issue will be resolved

Comment: I think the issue is your PHP code is not being executed as I see the code is printed back on the web page. Make sure your local server (apache/nginx) service is UP & RUNNING and properly configured with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this In Terminal :

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

if it's not working try to change the port of phpmyadmin to 3306 to 3307

Hoping it will be useful